# Delete From Table error

Tags: sql, vb.net

i'm trying to create a delete button to delete a record ....

here's my code:

```
    Dim SqlQuery As String = "DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE InvoiceNumber = " & id & ";"
    'id is public shared as integer , which is ListView1.SelectedItems(0).Text
    Dim SqlCommand As New OleDb.OleDbCommand

    With SqlCommand
        .CommandText = SqlQuery
        .Connection = conn
        .ExecuteNonQuery()
    End With
```

I get an exception in .ExecuteNonQuery(), the error is

```
 "ExecuteNonQuery() requires the command to have a transaction" ,
 "Validate transaction" , "ExecuteReaderInternal"
```

assume that the database is connected, got info and delete button is button3 .

Also i will show you my whole form code:

```
Public Class Report
Public id As Integer

Public conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
Public connstring As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Ramy\Documents\Beach.accdb"


Private Property RivieraDataSet As Object

Private Sub Report_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    conn.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub Report_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    If conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        Try
            conn.ConnectionString = connstring
            conn.Open()
            MsgBox("DataBase opened successfully!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
            loadlistview()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        End Try
    Else
        MsgBox("DataBase Error!!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    End If
    Dim reading As OleDb.OleDbDataReader
    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    Dim trans As OleDb.OleDbTransaction
    trans = conn.BeginTransaction
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM MyTable"
    cmd.Connection = conn
    cmd.Transaction = trans
    reading = cmd.ExecuteReader
    Dim i
    Do While reading.Read
        i = Val(reading.Item("Total")) + i
    Loop
    TextBox7.Text = i
    TextBox7.Text = Convert.ToDecimal(TextBox7.Text).ToString("N2") & " L.E"

End Sub

Sub loadlistview()
    ListView1.FullRowSelect = True
    ListView1.MultiSelect = False
    ListView1.View = View.Details

    ListView1.Columns.Clear()
    ListView1.Items.Clear()


    ListView1.Columns.Add("No", 30, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
    ListView1.Columns.Add("InvoiceDate", 125, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
    ListView1.Columns.Add("PersonsNumber", 70, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
    ListView1.Columns.Add("PersonPrice", 80, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
    ListView1.Columns.Add("CashierName", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
    ListView1.Columns.Add("Total", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left)



    Dim SqlQuery As String = "SELECT * FROM MyTable"
    Dim SqlCommand As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    Dim SqlAdapter As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim table As New DataTable

    With SqlCommand
        .CommandText = SqlQuery
        .Connection = conn
    End With

    With SqlAdapter
        .SelectCommand = SqlCommand
        .Fill(table)
    End With

    For i = 0 To table.Rows.Count - 1
        With ListView1
            .Items.Add(table.Rows(i)("InvoiceNumber"))
            With .Items(.Items.Count - 1).SubItems
                .Add(table.Rows(i)("InvoiceDate"))
                .Add(table.Rows(i)("PersonsNumber"))
                .Add(table.Rows(i)("PersonPrice"))
                .Add(table.Rows(i)("CashierName"))
                .Add(table.Rows(i)("Total"))
            End With
        End With
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub ListView1_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles ListView1.MouseClick

    Dim SqlQuery As String = "SELECT * FROM MyTable"
    Dim SqlCommand As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    Dim SqlAdapter As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim table As New DataTable

    With SqlCommand
        .CommandText = SqlQuery
        .Connection = conn
    End With

    With SqlAdapter
        .SelectCommand = SqlCommand

    End With



    If ListView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
        id = ListView1.SelectedItems(0).Text
        TextBox1.Text = id
        TextBox6.Text = ListView1.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(1).Text
        TextBox3.Text = ListView1.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(2).Text
        TextBox4.Text = ListView1.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(3).Text
        TextBox2.Text = ListView1.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(4).Text
        TextBox5.Text = ListView1.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(5).Text
    End If
End Sub



Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim SqlQuery As String = "DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE InvoiceNumber = " & id & ";"
    'id is public shared as integer , which is ListView1.SelectedItems(0).Text
    Dim SqlCommand As New OleDb.OleDbCommand

    With SqlCommand
        .CommandText = SqlQuery
        .Connection = conn
        .ExecuteNonQuery()
    End With

End Sub
End Class
```

I was searching for a mistake in my delete btn code for hours , but i can see everything is good..... but   .ExecuteNonQuery() is so annoying .

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: What does the error **say**?

Comment: Please explain, i'm new in visual basic

Comment: The Error says An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Comment: What's the exception message?

Comment: What is the datatype of the column 'InvoiceNumber' in the datatable?

Comment: data type is Autonumber. it's primary as well

Comment: Exception message is "ExecuteNonQuery() requires the command to have a transaction" , "Validate transaction" , "ExecuteReaderInternal"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Form_Load` you open a transaction for your GLOBAL connection.
This means that every command executed using that connection should be informed of this transaction (and you do it in the Form_Load event setting the Command.Transaction property).
But in other parts of your program, executing a command with that connection and not setting the Transaction property will raise the mentioned error.

Looking at your code above I would suggest to remove altogether the Transaction because, as is, you don't need it.

Simply remove these lines in Form_Load

```
Dim trans As OleDb.OleDbTransaction
trans = conn.BeginTransaction
...
cmd.Transaction = trans
```

Instead, if for motives not apparent from the code above, you insist in keeping the Transaction  then you should create the command from the connection so the transaction is passed to the command.

```
Dim SqlQuery As String = "DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE InvoiceNumber = " & id & ";"
Dim SqlCommand = conn.CreateCommand()
With SqlCommand
  .... 
End With
```

By the way, I really suggest you to remove that global connection variable. It is only a source of problems (check if open, transactions etc...) Just make a function that creates it for you and use it in a Using Statement whenever you need it

```
Public Function GetConnection() As OleDb.OleDbConnection
   Dim conn = New OleDb.OleDbConnection(connstring)
   conn.Open()
   return conn
End Function
```

And use it with [Using Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) that close and dispose the enclosed object also in case of exceptions

```
Using conn = GetConnection()
Using command = conn.CreateCommand()
    With command
       command.CommandText = "DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE InvoiceNumber = " & id & ";"
       command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End With
End Using
End Using
```

Pay also attention at possible sql injection scenarios. In your situation (reading an integer from a ListView) there are few problems, but a parameterized query is always better